# Unity3D: Setting AudioSource volume dynamically using AnimationCurve

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

Newcomer to Unity here. For this project, I am reading in an outside AnimationCurve, and attempting to use it to adjust the volume of my GameObject every frame in the Update function. I have found documentation on how to access the volume of my AudioSource GameObject component (this is working), but I can't figure out how to use my evaluated curve to update the volume.

[Screencap with imported AnimationCurve and evaluated values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8mxr.png)

My cs script is included below. Sorry if it's a bit opaque. This is for a neuroscience experiment, so I need to carefully control the animation curves. It reads in times and values (stored in currentCurveData) used to add keyframes to the new AnimationCurve (curveThisTrl) in the SetAnimationFrames() function.

The key part is in Update(). The initial tone.volume is correct, so I know it's reading that property from the GameObject. I can also see the correct curve values coming through in the Debug Log every frame, so I know the curve evaluation is working. It's just not changing the volume property of the GameObject as I want it to.

Hopefully this is enough information to spot a problem, but if not I can try to provide a test AnimationCurve for reproducibility. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public class AnimationControl : MonoBehaviour {

    private DataController dataControllerRef;
    private CurveDataSingleTrial currentCurveData;
    private float initTime;

    public AnimationCurve curveThisTrl;
    AudioSource tone;

    void Awake()
    {
        initTime = Time.time;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        // Get references to key objects in scene
        dataControllerRef = FindObjectOfType<DataController>(); // Has values from JSON
        tone = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Debug.Log(tone.volume);

        // query the DataController for the current curve data
        currentCurveData = dataControllerRef.GetCurrentCurveData();

        SetAnimationFrames();
    }

    void SetAnimationFrames()
    {
        int numKeyFrames = currentCurveData.keyframeTimes.Length;

        for (int c = 0; c < numKeyFrames; c++)
        {
            curveThisTrl.AddKey(currentCurveData.keyframeTimes[c], currentCurveData.keyframeVals[c]);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        float currTime = Time.time - initTime;
        tone.volume = curveThisTrl.Evaluate(currTime);
        Debug.Log(tone.volume);

    }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you are playing something, right.

Comment: Do you get the correct values when you log `currTime` and `curveThisTrl.Evaluate(currTime)` ?

Comment: @ Iggy, yes, all the values match the curve in both cases. Interestingly, if I do this a different way and add an Animation property, create an AnimationClip in script, and then use the same curve to animate the X position in the new clip (e.g. clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", curveThisTrl);), the object moves according to the curve. However, I still can't get the volume to change using the exact same method!

Comment: @jiveturkey, yes, there's an AudioSource that plays a 10 second tone on Awake. I can query it's starting volume with Debug.Log(tone.volume), but I can't change it with animation.

Comment: I had a similar issue with modifying the pitch too quickly on the Android platform.  Try updating the volume in steps or putting in a delay on the update.

Comment: Hm, the weird thing is if I manually create a relatively fast-changing curve (like the ones I'm trying to use in script) in the animator editor, the volume modulation keeps up just fine.